# Filter for RelationshipType in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

If a node has multiple incoming relationship of different types and i am fetching the graph for one specific relationship then other relationships are also coming attached to that node. My graph is something like this

> Person ---Works_In_Address---> Address
>
> Person ---Works_In_Address---> Address

If suppose I wants to query all the person works in bangalore, query like

> MATCH (p:Person)-[r:Works_In_Address{city: "bangalore"}]->(a:Address) RETURN r;

I am getting graph like

> Person ---Lives_In_Address---> Address <---Works_In_Address---

I queried for Works_In_Address but Lives_In_Address is also coming. I want to see result something like

> Person ---Works_In_Address---> Address

Answer (score 0):

Actually graph comes like

> Person ---Lives_In_Address---> Address <---Works_In_Address---

if we query like

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:Works_In_Address{city: "bangalore"}]->(a:Address) RETURN r;
```

To see actually the relationship returned we can see it in rows section of neo4j UI client, It's coming correctly with the above query.

Answer (score -1):

If you are querying for person, you should 'return p' not 'return r'.

Comment: If i will do "return p" then only person node i will get. But i wants to see the graph like : Person ---Works_In_Address---> Address. In that case how i have to query

Comment: @shaw.ram If "I wants to query all the person works in bangalore" you should be querying and expecting person nodes. Otherwise, if you query for relationships you should expect these relationships with their bounding nodes and all the other relationships between these nodes. As a recommendation, i would suggest that you add the city property to the address node instead of the relationship itself, in order to better describe real life scenarios.

Comment: I put city properties into the Address node but still got the same result for query something like : MATCH ()-[r:Works_In_Address]->(a:Address{city : "bangalore"}) RETURN r;